# Failed review test unfairly

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed a review test:

[image: The given answer suggests a line of code to solve the asker's issue and a link to more information called "Get a list of all installed Window's Updates".]

[Programmatically get a list of all installed updates in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698912/programmatically-get-a-list-of-all-installed-updates-in-windows)

The answer has been marked as spam.  However, it is clearly not spam.  It's not offensive, and it is a genuine attempt to answer the question.  Might be a bad answer, but it's definitely not spam.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: I am guessing there was a link in the post that was the cause of the issue which may or may not be clear by looking at a single post fits the flag.

Comment: What did the link point to?

Comment: direct link to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22188594) and to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52698912/programmatically-get-a-list-of-all-installed-updates-in-windows/54329097#54329097)

Comment: You were the second person to [fail the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22164254). Looks like a bad audit candidate, mods should clear the spam flags.

Comment: @FrankerZ the user is VP of Product Strategy at Action1 and the link points to their website. How is that not spam? On top of that the answer is a copy of an answer on https://www.quora.com/From-this-list-how-can-one-know-which-updates-to-install so even if it isn;t spam, it is plagiarized.

Comment: @rene: Linking to a page is not spam when the linked page is relevant to the question, which it appears to be. As for the Quora answer, that appears to be at most self-plagiarization. We're not an academic publication, so that is allowed here.

Comment: As an aside, could you crop your screenshot a bit please? It's very hard to see on mobile devices without zooming/panning.

Comment: @MSalters But we're still required to disclose our affiliation. You can link to your own blog post/GitHub/service but you have to tell people that's what you're doing.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Honestly, it was impossible to read on the laptop without opening the image separately and zooming in. OP, you can rollback if I edited out something important but the image includes both the answer and the audit message. The question is still available at the link so I don't think it's critical for it to be in the screenshot.

Comment: Regarding the links, I didn't know I could link to the original review, so thanks to those who pointed it out, and @BSMP for fixing.

Comment: @MSalters There are *lots* of things that can make something spam.  Suggesting a product not related to the question is one of them.  There are many more, such as a lack of disclosure of affiliation.  See the help center's pages on promotion, or some of the many meta questions on the topic, for more detailed information.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like spam to me, on closer inspection.

The link was `https://www.action1.com/kb/getting-a-list-of-all-installed-Windows-updates.html`, which isn't a Microsoft-oriented link.  If nothing else, it reads like the answerer is trying to sell other readers on their technical solution without disclosing affiliation or intent.

<sup>(What makes matters **worse** is that someone decided to actually *edit* the question...)</sup>

So I'm gonna disagree with the assertion that this isn't spam.  You've got to look at *everything* about a post to determine if it's spam or not.  Even the links.

Comment: What? You’ve gotta look at everything about a post when reviewing it? Come on, next you’ll be telling us we have to read the question before posting an answer. Don’t be ridiculous.

Comment: Fair point, I can see that there's an undisclosed affiliation. Well spotted.